# Bei minus ein/eins/einem Grad

Tags: grammatical-case, article, numbers

> Die Temperatur morgen bleibt bei minus ___ Grad.

Sollen wir "ein" oder "eins" oder "einem" benutzen?

Comment: **Ein Grad** ist richtig, vielfach hört man auch *bei (minus) einem Grad*, das ist aber falsch, man sagt ja auch nicht *bei (minus) zweier Grade*. *Eins Grad* ist ebenso falsch.

Comment: @Janke, was schreibst du denn da? _Bei eine**m** Grad_ ist vollkommen richtig. Vergleiche auch: _bei eine**m** Kilo_ oder _in eine**r** Sekunde_ oder _mit eine**m** Auto_.

Comment: @Janka: *zweier* ist schon wegen des Genitivs falsch, das hilft bei der Argumentation nicht.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Workaround: "Die Temperatur morgen bleibt bei -1 Grad" ;-)

Spaß beiseite:
"**Wo** (bleibt die Temperatur)" erfordert den Dativ, also wird "eins" so flektiert wie auf der von @Wobby verlinkten Seite ([Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Zahlen/Kardinal.html#Anchor-eins-35326)).
Richtig ist also

> "Die Temperatur morgen bleibt bei minus einem Grad"

Aber

> "Die Temperatur morgen bleibt bei minus zwei Grad"
>
> "Die Temperatur morgen bleibt bei minus drei Grad"
>  usw.

ist auch richtig. Hier bleibt das Zahlwort in seiner unflektierten Form erhalten, denn es sind ja mehrere Grad -> Plural!
Vgl. z.B.:

> "Wo ist das Kind untergebracht?" - "Bei einem Betreuer"
>   "Bei zwei Betreuern"
>    "Bei drei Betreuern"
>   usw.

Warum man dann nicht "Grad**e**" schreibt? Weil es eben so ist ;-) Siehe z.B. [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Grad):

> "GRAMMATIK     der Grad; Genitiv: des Grad[e]s, **Plural: die Grade
>   <aber: 30 Grad>**"

Answer (score 6):

Richtig

> Die Temperatur morgen bleibt bei minus ein/em Grad.
>   (The temperature tomorrow is one degree below zero)

Umgangssprache

> Die Temperatur morgen bleibt bei minus ein Grad / ein Grad unter null.

Genau Falsch

> Die Temperatur morgen bleibt bei minus eins Grad.

"Eins" ist relativ oft nur die Zahl, aber es anderen Bedeutungen hat.
In diesem Fall kann man "ein" oder "einem" schreiben oder sprachen, da "ein" gleich der Zahl "one" ist und "einem" gleich dem unbestimmten Artikel "a(n)" ist.
Wenn Du der Zahl schreibst, dann sollen der Satz mit anderen Zahlen funktionieren. Zum Beispiel: "ein Grad" und "vier Grade." (der Grad, die Grade, das ist egal)

[Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Zahlen/Kardinal.html#Anchor-eins-35326)

Comment: "'Eins' ist einfach die Ziffer." Das passt nicht ganz, es ist die Zahl Eins. Die Ziffer ist ein Bestandteil der Zahl. Da es sich in der Frage um ein (Temperatur-) Maß dreht, ist eine Zahl gefragt, nicht deren Bestandteile.

Comment: I tried to edit this answer, i.e. improve the various spelling mistakes and missing words etc. But somehow I get stuck because inadvertibly I will interfere with the meaning, and then I get caught in things I do not agree with in terms of content, not knowing is this a syntax mistake or just a contestable opinion. Please, Wobbly, could you try and correct spelling and syntax yourself?

Comment: Wofür soll 'normalerweise' eine Übersetzung sein?

Comment: Geht es nur mir so, dass ich mit diesem Deutsch-Englischen Kauderwelsch nichts anfangen kann? 
Bei den unverständlichen Formulierungen fällt mir sogar eine Korrektur schwer!

Comment: "Mal kann es 'ein' (Unbestimmter Artikel/Pronomen) oder mal einem (wie "a/an") sein." - auch, wenn es vielleicht nicht so gemeint war: Diese Aussage klingt, als verwandele sich "ein" in Abhängigkeit umgebender Buchstaben/Laute in "einem" (oder andersherum), ohne dass sich ein grammatikalischer Unterschied ergibt, und könnte damit zu Missverständnissen führen.

Comment: Ziffern verhalten sich zu Zahlen wie Buchstaben zu Wörtern, Ziffern sind einfach die Symbole, die man benutzt um Zahlen zu schreiben. Darüber hinaus kann »Ziffer« auch noch eine statistische Größe bedeuten (Geburtenziffer, Dunkelziffer). Aber ein Wort kann niemals eine Ziffer sein. Es kann aber ein Zahlwort sein, und das trifft auf *»eins«* zu.

Answer (score 2):

Für beide Varianten

> - bei minus ein Grad
> - bei minus ein**em** Grad

lassen sich Beispiele in schriftlichem Deutsch nachweisen. Somit halte ich beides für richtig, aber die undeklinierte Form

> bei minus ein Grad

kommt etwas häufiger vor. Im Zweifel würde ich daher diese Variante bevorzugen.

Man muss auch berücksichtigen, dass die Verwendung von *Minus* als Temperaturqualität und somit auch der Satzteil *bei ein Grad Minus* umgangssprachlich sind.

---

#### Beispiele

**bei minus ein Grad**

> *<sub>Entgegen aller Erwartungen hatte das Murmeltier Donnerstagfrüh seinen Schatten **bei minus ein Grad** Celsius und leichten Schneeschauern entdeckt und war zurück in den Bau gekrochen.</sub><sup>[Kronenzeitung](http://www.krone.at/552112)</sup>
>
>    <sub>Die Höchstwerte liegen **bei minus ein Grad** im Westen und minus neun Grad im Osten.</sub><sup>[Spiegel](http://www.spiegel.de/panorama/bibber-wetter-zieht-euch-warm-an-a-812088.html)</sup>
>
>    <sub>**Bei minus ein Grad** und fiesem Schneeregen finden sich für die Shows der Fall/Winter 2018 Saison allerdings nur ein paar Hobbyfotografen ohne Chance auf Akkreditierung und einige japanische Touristen ein, die sich verwirrt fragen, warum dieses lustig angestrahlte Haus, in das dauernd bescheuert angezogene junge Menschen rein und raus gehen, in keinem ihrer Berlin-Reiseführer steht.</sub><sup>[Stern](https://www.stern.de/lifestyle/mode/marie-von-den-benken/berlin-fashion-week--neue-saison--bekannte-gesichter-7826360.html)</sup>*

**bei minus einem Grad**

> *<sub>Es herrscht Dauerfrost **bei minus einem Grad** im Nordwesten und bis zu minus sieben Grad im Süden und in den Bergen.</sub><sup>[Rheinische Post](http://www.rp-online.de/panorama/deutschland/meteorologen-rechnen-mit-dauerfrost-aid-1.2011639)</sup>
>
>    <sub>Durch die Wärme der mehr als 200 Kerzen wolle er **bei minus einem Grad** die Blüten der Pfirsich- und Birnbäume schützen, sagte Siegel.</sub><sup>[Spiegel](http://www.spiegel.de/panorama/norsingen-obstbauer-will-baeume-mit-kerzen-vor-frost-schuetzen-a-1143982.html)</sup>
>
>     <sub>Die Temperaturen liegen tagsüber **bei minus einem Grad** im Norden und bei bis zu drei Grad im Rhein-Main-Gebiet.</sub><sup>[Welt](https://www.welt.de/regionales/hessen/article173186066/Knackig-kalte-Naechte-und-kein-Niederschlag.html)</sup>*